# Executing a Java program remotely from Java

Tags: java

Using Java on a client machine I wish to execute a different Java program on a server.

I have a Windows 7 laptop that I'm using as a client machine, and I wish to run a simple java program on a MacBook Pro (this will be the server) from the client. The program on the server will be stored there, so there won't be any need for uploading the code from the client.

I am already running some Java Selenium tests remotely using Seleniums remote web driver, however Selenium cannot do everything I want which is why I need to execute a simple java program that will use the robot class to trigger a few keyboard events.

Is this possible?

(Essentially I want to run a java program on a client machine that executes some keyboard events on a server machine.)

Comment: Use ServerSocket  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm

Comment: Quite weird setup, this requires a desktop session on the server, where you wish to insert your keyboard events.
I'd rather create a program that does the same (by API calls or scripting), but leave the keystrokes out of the picture.

Comment: You can use ssh to do this securely. You can call ssh from Java and use it to run a Java program.

Comment: The server will be running browser tests, one of which involves uploading a file which prompts the OS file browser. Selenium can only interact with the browser, so I just need to remotely execute a script that picks the correct file using the filw browser. Simply sending keyboard events seemed like the simpler solution. It should work independant of the OS. While using some API I assume it would have to be custom for windows/OSX. But I'm up for anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

Usual way to upload a file using Selenium is the following:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(<uploadId>)).sendKeys(<pathToTheFile>);
```

I hope it should be enough and you don't want to test browser specific popup dialog.